# What maintenance actions are required after a bird strike?

Tags: bird-strike

Does the SRM or AMM detail what Inspections to do following a bird strike? Do the engineers have to examine the bird remains too and report it to someone?

Comment: If there was, you'd find it in AMM Chapter 5, which is where the special inspections are.  If the bird made a major ding or penetrated the structure, there would likely be an incident report and there would be some effort to identify the breed and estimate the size and weight for data gathering purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the nature of the strike. If a glancing strike—e.g., off the top of the windscreen, or the upper surface of a wing—maybe none is needed. Other strikes could take out the windscreen (some have, in fact).